# Angular CLI with options Karma runner WebStorm

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-runner, webstorm

Is there a way to enter command line options in WebStorm's Karma runner so I can, for example, specify a different environment file? I linked a screenshot of what's available as options in the config window.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve using the CLI:

```
ng test --environment=my-new-env
```

But using KarmaRunner.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Possible in upcoming WebStorm 2019.1 - it allows passing command-line arguments in karma run configuration (see [WEB-29620](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29620)) using *Karma options:* field (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.1/run-debug-configuration-karma.html):

[image]